# For $ A,B \in M_n(\mathbb C) $, if $A^*AB=0$ then $AB=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose we have two square-matrices like $A,B$ in which the elements come from complex numbers.
Prove that if $A^*AB=0$ then $AB=0$.

My work :  I applied the star-operator on both sides of the equality but nothing good was achieved. I have no idea about the solution. I just think that it might be related to that star-operator.

Note : I'm new to linear-algebra so please write your answers as simple as possible.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Thank you for the answer. What was wrong with my title?

Comment: You are welcome. Regarding the title, the quantifiers are not pretty, and they detract from the content. In real math, quantifiers are often used inside the definition of a set, but for little else; in particular, they don't appear in text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $A^*AB=0$, multiplying on the left by $B^*$ you get 
$$
0=B^*A^*AB=(AB)^*AB.
$$
So now the proof is reduced to showing that if $X^*X=0$, then $X=0$. With a similar idea as above, for any $v\in \mathbb C^n$ we have 
$$
0=v^*X^*Xv=(Xv)^*Xv.
$$
This implies $Xv=0$, and as this can be done in particular for $v$ in the canonical basis, we get $X=0$.

Comment: Alternatively: instead of involving a vector, you can inspect the diagonal entries of $X^*X$, which is really the same at doing the computations for the standard basis vectors.

Comment: Yes, that's the way I would have done it.